# How can I figure out why MSMQ messages are not being delivered?

Tags: .net, msmq

I have an application that reads a message from a queue, does some work with the message, then submits a message to an output queue.  Let's call this the sender side.

I use a dedicated server for MSMQ.  Let's call this the server side.

The problem is that the messages never shows up in the output queue.

I've enabled End2End logging on the sender and the server.  In the sender side it says "Message sent over network", and in the queue server side all it says is "Message came over network".  So the message leaves the sender, and is received by the server, but does not get put in the output queue.

In code (.NET 4.5.1) I've tried enabling dead letter journal-ling.  Here's my code for sending a message:

```
// Enqueue an object.
public static void EnqueueObject(object obj, MessageQueue queue)
{
    using (Message msg = new Message(obj, queue.Formatter))
    {
        msg.UseJournalQueue = false;
        msg.UseDeadLetterQueue = true;

        lock (queue)
            queue.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

I find that messages show up in the journals of other queues earlier in the process, but nothing shows up in the Dead Letter Journals of the sender or the server.

All I have to go on is the End2End event log output on the server side that says "Message came over network" and then nothing else.

All my queues have Full Control granted to Everybody and ANONYMOUS LOGON.  Other applications using the same underlying queue code working with other queues on the same server work.  It's just this one application with this one output queue.

Where's my message?

Comment: hi, is it Transactional queue?

Comment: nope, just a regular queue

Comment: Seems to be some sort of incompatibility between whatever MSMQ runs on Win2k8 R2 and .NET 4.5.1.  We'd previously relied on a .NET 3.5 patch.  Maybe this is a .NET 4.5.1 regression?  In any event, I moved all MSMQ-dependent code into an assembly targeting .NET 3.5, and all's well.  Go figure.